# Image parsing issue with @tensorflow-models/mobilenet in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, multipartform-data

I've created one API where I need to check Nudity, violence and vulgarity before uploading images to AWS. I found `@tensorflow-models/mobilenet` but the code gives me a runtime error like below.

```
throw new Error('pixels passed to tf.browser.fromPixels() must be either an ' +
          ^

Error: pixels passed to tf.browser.fromPixels() must be either an HTMLVideoElement, HTMLImageElement, HTMLCanvasElement, ImageData in browser, or OffscreenCanvas, ImageData in webworker or {data: Uint32Array, width: number, height: number}, but was Object

    at fromPixels_ (/Users/apple/Documents/flutter_projects/rest_shopping/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:26357:15)
    at Object.fromPixels__op [as fromPixels] (/Users/apple/Documents/flutter_projects/rest_shopping/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-core/dist/tf-core.node.js:5612:29)
```

Relevent Code:

```
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');
const models = require('@tensorflow-models/mobilenet');

route.post("/upload-image", upload.single('image'), async (req, res) => {
  const image = req.file;
  console.log(image);

  const model = await models.load();

  const predictions = await model.classify(image);

  console.log('Predictions: ');
  console.log(predictions);
  res.send('File uploaded successfully!');
});
```

**Note**: I'm not using any webpage to upload images. These are mobile APIs where images are being uploaded from mobile app to server

Comment: If it wants (amongst other possibilities) an image, maybe `let image = new Image(); image.src = "path/to/the/file";`.

Comment: Still giving me same error with another expected thing. `pixels passed to tf.browser.fromPixels() must be either an HTMLVideoElement, HTMLImageElement, HTMLCanvasElement, ImageData in browser, or OffscreenCanvas, ImageData in webworker or {data: Uint32Array, width: number, height: number}, but was Image`

Comment: That seems unfortunate, as the docs at [HTMLImageElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement) say "The Image() constructor creates and returns a new HTMLImageElement object [...]". There must be something I am not understanding.

Comment: Now I'm able to parse it after adding these two lines
`const file = fs.readFileSync(image.path);`
`const adaptedImg = tf.node.decodeImage(file, 3);`
`const predictions = await model.classify(adaptedImg);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I'm able to parse it after adding these two lines

```
const file = fs.readFileSync(image.path);
const adaptedImg = tf.node.decodeImage(file, 3);
```

Use **adaptedImg** to classify

```
const predictions = await model.classify(adaptedImg);
```